# Collapse columns and insert new row?

Tags: python, pandas

My data:

```
df
Out[79]: 
    INC Theme Theme_Hat TRAIN_TEST
0   123     A       NaN      TRAIN
1   124     A       NaN      TRAIN
2   125     A       NaN      TRAIN
3   126     A       NaN      TRAIN
4   127     A       NaN      TRAIN
5   128     A       NaN      TRAIN
6   129     A       NaN      TRAIN
7   130     A       NaN      TRAIN
8   131     B       NaN      TRAIN
9   132     B         B       TEST
10  133     B         A       TEST
11  134     B         A       TEST
12  135     B         A       TEST
```

I am trying to collapse the `Theme_Hat` column into the `Theme` column while maintaining the `TRAIN_TEST` indicator. I have used a `for` loop below, but my gut tells me there must be some more `pandas`-esque solution out there. The attempt below doesn't reach my desired output, as `TEST` is continuously duplicated throughout `df` instead of the `TRAIN` info being preserved. Here's my desired output:

```
Out[81]: 
    INC Theme TRAIN_TEST
0   123     A      TRAIN
1   124     A      TRAIN
2   125     A      TRAIN
3   126     A      TRAIN
4   127     A      TRAIN
5   128     A      TRAIN
6   129     A      TRAIN
7   130     A      TRAIN
8   131     B      TRAIN
9   132     B      TRAIN
10  132     B      TEST
11  133     B      TRAIN
12  133     A      TEST
13  134     B      TRAIN
14  134     A      TEST
15  135     B      TRAIN
16  135     A      TEST
```

Here's what I've done so far:

```
# copy so we can reference the original dataframe as rows are inserted into df
df2 = df.copy(deep = True)
no_nulls = df2[df2['Theme_Hat'].notnull()]

# get rid of the Theme_Hat column for final dataframe (since we're migrating that info into Theme)
df.drop('Theme_Hat', inplace = True, axis = 1)

# I'm sure there's some pandas built-in functionality that 
# can handle this better than a for loop
for idx in no_nulls.index:
    # reference the unchanged df2 for INC, Theme_Hat, and TRAIN_TEST info
    new_row = pd.DataFrame({"INC": df2.loc[idx, 'INC'], 
                            "Theme": df2.loc[idx, 'Theme_Hat'],
                            "TRAIN_TEST": df2.loc[idx, 'TRAIN_TEST']}, index = [idx+1])
    print(new_row, '\n\n')

    # insert the new row right after the row at the current index
    df = pd.concat([df.ix[:idx], new_row, df.ix[idx+1:]]).reset_index(drop = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
print (df.set_index(['INC','TRAIN_TEST'])
         .stack()
         .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
         .reset_index(name='Theme'))

    INC TRAIN_TEST Theme
0   123      TRAIN     A
1   124      TRAIN     A
2   125      TRAIN     A
3   126      TRAIN     A
4   127      TRAIN     A
5   128      TRAIN     A
6   129      TRAIN     A
7   130      TRAIN     A
8   131      TRAIN     B
9   132       TEST     B
10  132       TEST     B
11  133       TEST     B
12  133       TEST     A
13  134       TEST     B
14  134       TEST     A
15  135       TEST     B
16  135       TEST     A
```

Solution with [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html), remove column by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) and `NaN` by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
print (pd.melt(df, id_vars=['INC','TRAIN_TEST'], value_name='Theme')
         .drop('variable', axis=1)
         .dropna(subset=['Theme']))

    INC TRAIN_TEST Theme
0   123      TRAIN     A
1   124      TRAIN     A
2   125      TRAIN     A
3   126      TRAIN     A
4   127      TRAIN     A
5   128      TRAIN     A
6   129      TRAIN     A
7   130      TRAIN     A
8   131      TRAIN     B
9   132       TEST     B
10  133       TEST     B
11  134       TEST     B
12  135       TEST     B
22  132       TEST     B
23  133       TEST     A
24  134       TEST     A
25  135       TEST     A
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.lreshape` which automatically drops `NaNs` by default. Then, you can combine the two columns under consideration to take their union of values in a single column. Finally, sort these according to the `INC` column values.

```
pd.lreshape(df, {'Theme': ['Theme','Theme_Hat']}).sort_values('INC').reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]